# Linked list prints segmentation fault

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am learning about linked lists in c and when i try printing the head's base_pri in main() it just gives me a segmentation fault. 
Here is my code:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct iorb {
int base_pri;
struct iorb *link;
} IORB;

IORB *head = NULL;
void makeList(IORB *h, int s);

int main(){
  makeList(head, 15);

  printf("%d\n", head->base_pri);

    return 0;
}

 void makeList(IORB *h, int s){
      while(s > 0){
        IORB *temp = (IORB*)malloc(sizeof(IORB));
        temp->base_pri = (rand() % 20);
        temp->link = h;
        h = temp;
        s--;
    }
 }
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You pass `h` by value to `makeList`. When you print it, `h` is still `NULL`.

Comment: Take a debugger to run your code. You will notice that `head` did not change after calling `makeList`. Why?

Comment: "Any advice would be appreciated." => ***DON'T USE GLOBAL.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing `head` to `makeList()` as a call by value, when control comes back to calling function `head` still didn't get modify i.e its still `NULL` and next when you do `head->base_pri` i.e `NULL->base_pri` obviously it gives seg. fault.

Instead passing `head` to `makeList()` pass the address of `head` as

```
typedef struct iorb {
        int base_pri;
        struct iorb *link;
} IORB;
IORB *head = NULL;
void makeList(IORB **h, int s);
int main(){
        makeList(&head, 15);/* pass head address */
        printf("%d\n", head->base_pri);
        return 0;
}
void makeList(IORB **h, int s){
        while(s > 0){
                IORB *temp = (IORB*)malloc(sizeof(IORB));
                temp->base_pri = (rand() % 20);
                temp->link = (*h);
                (*h) = temp;
                s--;
        }
}
```

Comment: yes @SergeBallesta that's also one way to achieve the same but OP didn't seem to `return` any `ptr` from `makeList()` as return type mentioned is `void`

Answer (score 0):

Hi see you mistakes below:-

In the below line of code you are passing head and its value is NULL
    makeList(head, 15);

and now actually you are calling it like:-

```
makeList(NULL, 15);
```

And it does not mean anything. Which is wrong

Correct it like below and pass the address of head not the value i.e. NULL address

```
 makeList(&head, 15);
```

Once you correct your function call like above you have to change your function signature like below:-

Also you need to modify your logic like below. Here you are implementation a circular link list.

```
void makeList(IORB **h, int s){
      while(s > 0){
        IORB *temp = (IORB*)malloc(sizeof(IORB));
        temp->base_pri = (rand() % 20);
        temp->link = NULL;
                    if(*h == NULL)
                       h = temp;
                    else
                    {
                       temp->link = *h;
                       *h = temp;
                    }
                    s--;
    }
 }
```

Also to print the list modify your code like below in your main function:-

```
  IORB *temp = head;
  while(temp != NULL)
  {
      printf("%d\n", head->base_pri);
      temp = temp->link;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is this. I'm assuming `int s` is the size of the linked list that you wish to create. Your `makeList(IORB *h, int s)` should look something more like this, (If you want to avoid double pointers)

In your main you can create a head node like: `head = (IORB*) malloc(sizeof(IORB));` and then call your `makeList(head, 15);`

And your `makeList` function would look something like so:

```
IORB* temp = h; //set temp to head (since we made sure head is not NULL)

while(s > 0){
    temp->link = (IORB*)malloc(sizeof(IORB)); //create it's next node
    temp->link->base_pri = (rand() % 20);
    temp = temp->link; //remember to move temp pointer to the newly created node
    s--;    
}
```